# How to check if MacBook screen is genuine?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I bought used MacBook Pro and have suspicion that screen was replaced and the replacement is not genuine. Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terminal.app you can paste this command to find out which display you're using:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

which should return all of your Graphics/Display information.

- Now the question is what is genuine? Apple and just about every other company uses parts from many different manufacturers at any given time. The only way to know is by identifying the exact model and serial number of your MacBook Pro and then determining which part was used in that particular batch.