# How to know if a MacBook Pro 15" screen is genuine?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I bought a used MacBook Pro 15" 2016 and suspect that the screen was replaced and the replacement is not genuine. I went to terminal.app and checked using this code:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

I got the result below, but I don't know whether the information verifies that this is a genuine screen or not because I couldn't figure out what it means.

```
Graphics/Displays:

Intel HD Graphics 530:

  Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 530
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
  Vendor: Intel
  Device ID: 0x191b
  Revision ID: 0x0006
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.29 [3.2.8]
  Metal Family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily macOS 2
  Displays:
    Color LCD:
      Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
      Resolution: 2880 x 1800 Retina
      Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
      Connection Type: Internal

Radeon Pro 455:

  Chipset Model: AMD Radeon Pro 455
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width: x8
  VRAM (Total): 2 GB
  Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
  Device ID: 0x67ef
  Revision ID: 0x00c7
  ROM Revision: 113-C980AF-908
  VBIOS Version: 113-C9801AP-028
  EFI Driver Version: 01.A0.908
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.29 [3.2.8]
  Metal Family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily macOS 2
```

I went to bestfirms.com to check the screen resolution for this model and it says 1680 x 1050. That's why I question the authenticity of the screen.

Comment: This [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116835/how-to-check-if-macbook-screen-is-genuine?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: 2880 x 1800 is the native resolution. Retina scales it to 1680 x 1050 to make things larger while maintaining crisp sharp text and images.  The only way you can tell if it is not legit is to take it apart and see if the part is not the same as an identical model.  It's legit and so long as it works it should be fine.

Comment: There's no market for anyone to produce third-party alternative display parts for Apple laptops in sufficient quantity to get a cheap price.